# Unidirectional pipes in C

Tags: c, pipe, fork, parent-child, child-process

I'm having trouble trying to work out how to make individual pipes for a parent process and a child process to act in a unidirectional fashion. I.e.: a descriptor for the parent and a different descriptor for its child.

Here's what I have:

```
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int parent[2];
    int child[2];
    pid_t pid;

    int num = 0;

    pipe(parent);
    pipe(child);

    pid =fork();

    if(pid > 0){ // do parent stuff

        num = 5;

        write(parent[1], &num, sizeof(num));
        printf("Parent with pid %d sent value: %d\n", getpid(), num);

        close(parent[1]);

    }else{ // do child stuff

        read(child[0], &num, sizeof(num));
        printf("Child with pid %d received value: %d\n", getpid(), num);

        close(child[0]);

        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output:

`Parent with pid 31702 sent value: 5`

I know I'm supposed to close some of the descriptors at some point in there before the `read()` and `write()` commands, but it seems no matter what I close either the child response prints before the parent can `write()` or I end up with a broken pipe. Where should I close the descriptors to successfully use these pipes unidirectionally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell, that's not how you should work with pipes.

A pipe has a `read 0` and `write 1` end.

In your case, the child is reading from `child[0]`, but nobody is going to write to the child through `child[1]`. The parent is going to write to the `parent[1]`.

Try using a single pipe (change `child[0]` to `parent[0]`). And make sure you delete the ends you wont be using in the respective processes

Comment: so it isn't possible to have a pipe for the parent and another for the child and still have successful IPC?

Comment: You can do IPC using a single pipe

Comment: What about when the parent forks N times? how would I communicate from the parent to each child?

Comment: Have one pipe for each child you make

Comment: So in that case, it would be how I have it above?

Comment: In your case you have two pipes for one child :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136514/discussion-between-darrel-holt-and-faiz-halde).

Answer (score 1):

You're making two pipes and then only using one end of each of them; the communication doesn't work because nobody is paying any attention to the *other* end of either. `parent` and `child` are totally independent pipes, what you send on one doesn't appear on the other. You only need one pipe:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int pipefd[2];
    pid_t pid;

    int num = 0;

    pipe(pipefd);

    pid = fork();

    if(pid > 0){ // do parent stuff
        close(pipefd[0]); // close the reading end

        num = 5;

        write(pipefd[1], &num, sizeof(num)); // write on the writing end
        printf("Parent with pid %d sent value: %d\n", getpid(), num);

    }else{ // do child stuff
        close(pipefd[1]); // close the writing end

        read(pipefd[0], &num, sizeof(num)); // read on the reading end
        printf("Child with pid %d received value: %d\n", getpid(), num);

        exit(0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A pipe is already unidirectional, and it gives you two ends back: a writing end and a reading end. You just have to use each one appropriately.

Comment: By unidirectional I mean a pipe can only be used to either read, or write; not both on the same pipe.

Comment: @DarrelHolt a pipe has two ends. What goes in one end comes out the other end. Otherwise, it wouldn't exactly be useful.

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't be called a pipe if otherwise. Thank you for clarifying and providing a code example.